# wifi fail: /lib/firmware erased during boot

Tags: wireless, 13.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

My computer is a Dell Latitude E6420. After a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 install, the wifi is not working.

The wifi hardware is, result of `sudo lspci | grep Network` :

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

The wifi is working on live CD. If I boot in maintenance mode, the wifi is working (after having reinstalled the firmware before shutdown).

On /var/log/syslog I have `iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode' failed`.

The folder /lib/firmware should be populated with firmware, but it is empty. I repopulate it with a `sudo aptitude reinstall linux-firmware`, but after the next boot it is empty again.

After booting I can make wifi work by running the following commands:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall linux-firmware
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But the firmware files installed in /lib/firmware are erased again, and after the next boot I have to retype the previous commands to make it work again.

Thank you for for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the origin of the problem. I was responsible for this Error:

On Ubuntu 12.10 I had this line in my  `/etc/fstab`

```
tmpfs /lib/firmware tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

I added this line, and some others, following recipes I found on the net to increase the responsiveness of my computer.

With this entry it is clear that firmware will not be persistent.

I removed the line and that fixed my problem.